# Removing element by EQ filtering doesn't remove the element from jQuery Object

Tags: jquery, object

I used this code to match list of elements:

```
var previewItems = preview.find('.items').children().not('.heads');
```

Everything works fine, but when I try to remove one of the items by choosing it's EQ, after it removes from the DOM, it keeps in the jQuery Object of matched elements.

```
previewItems.eq(index).remove();
alert(previewItems.eq(index)); // [object Object]
```

Why the jQuery keeps the element in the group of the matched elements?

Comment: Keep in mind jQuery objects are considered immutable. Even `add()` builds and returns a new jQuery object, it does not update the existing one. In the same way, `filter()` (and `slice()`) allow you to build a new jQuery object without some elements from the original.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why the jQuery keeps the element in the group of the matched elements?

In case you want to do something with it after removing it. `remove` removes the element from the DOM, but you may well want to do something further (like adding it elsewhere in the DOM or retrieving information from it).

You can remove it from the set using [`slice`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) or [`not`](http://api.jquery.com/not) or [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) (or more accurately: You can get a *new* object with all the same elements except the ones omitted by `slice`/`not`):

```
previewItems.eq(index).remove();
previewItems = previewItems.not(previewItems[index]);
```