# Remove element at certain index from object jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a small problem. I have a jquery object stored inside var like this

```
var buttons = $(data).find('.buttons>button');
```

When i write out buttons it returns me this :

```
0: button#pc_0.btn.btn-outline-dark
1: button#pc_1.btn.btn-outline-dark
2: button#pc_2.btn.btn-outline-dark
length: 3
prevObject: r.fn.init(35) [text, title, text, meta, text, meta, text, link, text, link, text, link, text, script, text, script, text, script, text, script, text, script, text, script, text, div.d-flex.justify-content-end.bg-dark.mb-3, text, div.jumbotron.jumbotron-fluid.text-center, text, div.container, text, footer.footer, text, script, text]
__proto__: Object(0)
```

This looks good. But my problem is that I can't remove the element at a certain index. I tried few methods like this .

```
$(buttons).remove('#pc_1');
```

or

```
$(buttons).eq(2).remove();
```

But nothing works. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Do you mean "remove from the jQuery object", "remove from the DOM", or both?

Comment: Remove from jquery object. Basically as you can see i have 3 buttons inside object. After i call remove i want to have only 2.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18231065/removing-element-by-eq-filtering-doesnt-remove-the-element-from-jquery-object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean "remove from the jQuery object," you'd use [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
buttons = buttons.filter(index => index !== 1);
// or
buttons = buttons.filter((_, element) => element.id !== "pc_1");
// etc.
```

or passing in a selector:

```
buttons = buttons.filter(":not([id=pc_1])");
// or
buttons = buttons.filter(":not(:eq(1))");
// etc.
```

Live Example:

```js
let buttons = $("button");
console.log(buttons.map((_, e) => e.id).get());
buttons = buttons.filter(":not([id=pc_1])");
console.log(buttons.map((_, e) => e.id).get());
```

```html
<button id="pc_0" class="btn btn-outline-dark">0</button>
<button id="pc_1" class="btn btn-outline-dark">0</button>
<button id="pc_2" class="btn btn-outline-dark">0</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

You've clarified that yes, you do mean "remove from the jQuery object," but just for others coming to this question and answer later:

If you mean "remove from the DOM," your `.eq` example would work with the index 1 rather than 2 (`eq` is 0-based):

```
button.eq(1).remove();
```

or again, filter but this time keeping just the target element, and then `remove`:

```
buttons.filter((_, element) => element.id === "pc_1").remove();
```

**But**, as that particular element has an `id`, if you're removing based on that ID, it would be simpler to just do this:

```
$("#pc_1").remove();
```

Comment: *(Silly of me to answer when of course this has been asked and answered. Made the post a CW, but having written it, seemed a shame to delete.)*